# running a lex program in linux mint

Tags: lex

I am trying to run a lex program in linux mint.I saved that file as abc.l,now i am trying to compile this file in the terminal by typing the following commands:

vi abc.l

lex abc.l

gcc lex.yy.c -lfl

but after the last command it is saying that no such file or directory.

please help me out in running the program.

Answer (score 5):

First of all check if you have installed Lex on your system by doing a "man lex" .
If not installed,you need to install Lex & Yacc tools by typing these in the command prompt

```
$sudo apt-get install flex
$sudo apt-get install bison
```

For compiling try this command,

```
$ cc -w lex.yy.c -ll
```

Then to run the actual program,type

```
$./a.out
```